# Matlab function similar to filter

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I am trying to write a matlab function that will act like the filter function, but for some reason it works for only the first 9 elements in the input I tested, and all of the other elements in the output are fifferent:

```
function y = difference_equation_solver(x,a,b,N)
    b = b(:)';
    a = a(:)';
    nb = length(b);
    na = length(a);
    Nx = length(x);
    y = zeros(1, N);
    for n = 1:N
        y(n) = b(1) * x(n);
        for k = 2:nb
            if n >= k
                y(n) = y(n) + b(k) * x(n-k+1);
            end
         end
        for k = 2:na
            if n >= k
                y(n) = y(n) - a(k) * y(n-k+1);
            end
        end
        if n < Nx
            x=[x(2:end),0];
        end
    end
end
```

I would like to know what the problem is.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. I would recommend you to start with an FIR filter before going to an IIR. Nevertheless, you are not supplying any comparison to make it make the error reproducible. Additionally, are you aware that your input data is deleted as `n` is being incremented, why would you do that?

Comment: Why is the input data deleted as n is being incremented?

Comment: Deleting was not the correct wording, it is being overwritten with zeros.